# Google Search console reports home page blocked by robots.txt and search results only show the domain name even though it isn't blocked

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, search-results, meta-description

For the last few days I haven't seen the title and meta description in Google search results. When I inspected URL in search console, I got this error message:

> URL is on Google, but has issues.
>
> Coverage: Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt

It isn't blocked by robots and it's also in the sitemap.

I have checked the CMS, meta data is updated.

### URL inspection in Search Console

[image: URL inspection in Search Console]

### Live testing in search console

[image: Live testing in search console]

### Title and Description is not Appearing in SERP

[image: Title and Description is not Appearing in SERP]

Comment: When did you last update robots.txt?   The [robots testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) shows that the home page should be allowed now.  You might still get that message if you had disallowed it any time in the past couple months.

Comment: There are some problems with your robots.txt file that you should fix, but they probably aren't related to this.   1. Remove blank lines between `User-Agent`, `Allow`,` and `Disallow`.   Blank links are not allowed there per the spec.  2. Remove the `Allow: /` rule.  It is not needed because allowing everything is already the default. It could only confuse some crawlers.   3. Remove all the rules that start with `Disallow: http` or remove the URL portions except the path.   Disallowed items must start with `/`.  4. Remove duplicate rules.

Comment: 5. Remove redundant rules like `Disallow: ?source=`, `Disallow: /customer/account/`, and `Disallow: /index.php/vendorform/view/index/` which are covered by other rules.  6.  Add a space after the `disallow:` in `Disallow:*--*`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for helping out.
I tried robots testing tool and got this error
**robots.txt fetch failed**
You have a robots.txt file that we are currently unable to fetch. In such cases we stop crawling your site until we get hold of a robots.txt, or fall back to the last known good robots.txt file. Learn more.

Comment: It was last updated 9 months ago.

Comment: I am also getting error with sitemap. Everything was working smoothly and suddenly, it happened. Sitemap could not be read. 
General HTTP error. 
1 instance. 
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure that your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided, and then resubmit.

Comment: It looks like Googlebot can't access your robots.txt file. Maybe some security system on your server or website is blocking Googlebots IP addresses?

Comment: I have tested robots.txt with serverheaders website and I got 200 for Googlebot. But, search console can't fetch the robots nor sitemap